# Get URL data with slash by PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get URL data by PHP. The basic folder structure is as follows,

[www.aaa.com](http://www.aaa.com)

- index.php
- /p/
- /p/index.php

I am try to access URL data when URL is as following

[www.aaa.com/p/aa/bb/cc](http://www.aaa.com/p/aa/bb/cc)

I need to get aa, bb, and cc data. Therefore I edit .htacess file as follows.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

IndexIgnore *

RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(/.*)?/?$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

New added code is,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

My index.php file code is as follows. ([www.aaa.com/p/index.php](http://www.aaa.com/p/index.php))

```
<?php


$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptName = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

for ($i= 0; $i < sizeof($scriptName); $i++)
{
    if ($requestURI[$i] == $scriptName[$i])
    {
        unset($requestURI[$i]);
    }
}

$command = array_values($requestURI);

echo $command[0];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $command[1];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $command[2];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $command[3];
?>
```

When I try to go [www.aaa.com/p/aa/bb/cc](http://www.aaa.com/p/aa/bb/cc) link it gives following error

> Error 500 - Internal Server Error An error was encountered while
> processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition.
> Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

But when I go to [www.aaa.com/p/?aa/bb/cc](http://www.aaa.com/p/?aa/bb/cc) link it give following data.

```
?aa

aa

bb
```

How can I get URL detail using [www.aaa.com/p/aa/bb/cc](http://www.aaa.com/p/aa/bb/cc) link.

Server-side error log,

> [Wed Mar 02 10:14:25.562964 2022] [core:error] [pid 2030552:tid
> 47127218218752] [client 67.176.109.142:60672] AH00124: Request
> exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
> configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
> limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
> https://www.aaa.com/p/      [Wed Mar 02 09:59:55.810234 2022]
> [core:error] [pid 1947129:tid 47127302268672] [client
> 112.134.216.244:31634] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
> 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
> 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
> https://www.aaa.com/p/?a/aa/bb

Comment: What do your error logs show? 500 errors need to be looked at on the server, not the browser/client.

Comment: Internal Server Error An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

Comment: How can i get error logs in server side?

Comment: There is no error in server log

Comment: _"There is no error in server log"_ - then you are most likely not looking in the correct location.

Comment: https://www.aa.com/p/?aa/aa/bb give values not https://www.aa.com/p/aa/aa/bb this link

Comment: You need to look at server set up and figure out where your error logs are going.

Comment: I put server side error log. Please check